# HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript Learning Resources

Tags: javascript, api, html, canvas, css

I am looking around for some in depth resources on HTML features such as `<audio>`, `<video>` and `<canvas>` and how JS and CSS/CSS3 can be used to create dynamic graphs/games and illustrations with the `<canvas>` tag, I have read a 2 books on both CSS3 and HTML5, they were more of just an overview of "the future" rather than practical applications.

I am looking for more of a project based book/web resource that I can take from start to finish to learn the fundamentals.

Comment: I wouldn't blame those authors -- neither HTML5 nor CSS3 have been standardized yet, so they're still things of "the future".

Comment: I agree but that said, examples of Canvas games are popping up here and there so the capability to learn about them is there already, granted they may change slightly in future.

Comment: @casablanca, large portions of html5 and css3 are already standardized. It took over a decade to standardize all of the css2 spec. It is impractical to wait until the entire spec is 'recommended'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) and understand that [javascript is not, you know, the silly javascript we do everyday](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/) :)

Disclaimer: I absolutely love javascript and I never thought of it as silly. I used the phrase silly cos chromeexperiments original quote `Not your mother's JavaScript` may offend the OP

Answer (score 4):

[HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/) is a great resource to learn about the new features in CSS3 and HTML5. It's not a start-to-finish guide, but it does provide lots of in-depth tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Oops... new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks.

- [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) Helping you implement HTML5 today.
- [HTML5 Gallery](http://html5gallery.com/) A showcase of sites using HTML5 markup.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sites of the browser developer (chrome, mozilla labs, ...). There is plenty of documentation

Answer (score 0):

- [WHATWG's blog](http://blog.whatwg.org/) Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group’s blog.
- [When can I use](http://caniuse.com/) Compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG.